# How can I find which projects reference a specific dll in my solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll, resharper

I use VS 2010 Ultimate edition. And I have ReSharper installed.

**How** can I **get** the **list of projects within my solution that references a specific dll** (for example entityframework.dll)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I search by a reference name, solution-wise, to see in which projects it was referenced?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416324/can-i-search-by-a-reference-name-solution-wise-to-see-in-which-projects-it-was)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on an assembly reference in Solution Explorer, select `Project Hierarchy`. This gives a list with projects containing usages of the assembly in the solution, nicely ordered in solution folders and all.

Comment: Is this a feature specific to 2010 Ultimate or ReSharper? Could you include that information in your answer?

Comment: @Zack it's a [resharper feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Code_Analysis__Project_Hierarchy.html) and I don't immediately see a way of getting something similar in virgin VS

Comment: @Zack see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7416654/27581) for a way to do it without Resharper